# Is there a way to get the highest and lowest scores using just PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a score table for students in a class. All tests and exam scores for subjects are collated and recorded there.

```
CREATE TABLE `scores_primary` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca5` float(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ca6` float(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affective` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `psychomotor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[image: A student's score sheet]

The Total column is automatically calculated from the controller. i.e all test scores + exam scores.
Then the highest and lowest scores are gotten based on the total scores.

Everything works fine but due to present circumstances (Covid-19 Pandemic), changes need to made and that is where the problem now surfaces.

Now, before schools were shut down, only test scores were inputted (i.e from ca1 to ca6). They were not able to write their exams, hence a blank spot for the exam column.

To rectify that, a conclusion was made to calculate the total of all the CAs, multiply it by 40 and divide by 60.

CAs Total X 40 /60

That would give the exam scores.

I'm not very knowledgeable in coding. One can say I'm worse than a novice. However, I tried to calculate the exam and Total scores in the view.
I'm now stuck as to how to get the highest and lowest scores since they were gotten from a query

**The model for highest/lowest score**

```
  public function GetHighestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select_max('tot_score');
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        return $this->db->get('scores_primary')->row(); 
    }

    public function GetLowestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select_min('tot_score');
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        return $this->db->get('scores_primary')->row(); 
    }
```

**The controller for highest and lowest score**

```
public function GetHighestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id)
    {
        $data = $this->primary_model->GetHighestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id); 
        return $data->tot_score;
    }


    public function GetLowestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id)
    {
        $data = $this->primary_model->GetLowestScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id); 
        return $data->tot_score;
    }
```

**The view**

```
 <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $CI->GetHighestScore($value->subject_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id, $value->class_id); ?></td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $CI->GetLowestScore($value->subject_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id); ?></td>
```

Since I calculated the exam and total scores from the view, it has made the above codes null because the total score is now calculated straight in the view.

Is there a way for me now to get the highest and lowest in class using the calculation I made? or how do I make this calculations in the controller so that the total, highest and lowest in class are automatically generated like they use to?

**Contoller**

```
function assigngradeAction() 
{
      for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post('number')); $i++)
                {

                    $data[]=array(
                        'section_id' => $this->input->post('section_id'),
                        'subject_id' => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
                        'class_id' => $this->input->post('class_id')[$i],
                        'student_id' => $this->input->post('student_id')[$i],
                        'session_id' => $this->input->post('session_id'),
                        'ca1' => $this->input->post('ca1')[$i],
                        'ca2' => $this->input->post('ca2')[$i],
                        'ca3' => $this->input->post('ca3')[$i],
                        'ca4' => $this->input->post('ca4')[$i],
                        'project' => $this->input->post('project')[$i],
                        'affective' => $this->input->post('affective')[$i],
                        'psychomotor' => $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i],
                        'exam' => $this->input->post('exam')[$i],
            'tot_score'=> $this->input->post('ca1')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca2')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca3')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca4')[$i] + $this->input->post('project')[$i] + $this->input->post('affective')[$i] + $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i] + $this->input->post('exam')[$i],

        }






        //var_dump($data);

        $inserted = $this->primary_model->add2($data2);
        if($inserted)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">Grade Added successfully</div>');
            //Echo back success json
            redirect('admin/teacher/GetStudentForSubject');
        }

    }
```

**View**

```
 <tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;white-space: nowrap;height:30px;">
<?php echo $CI->GetSubjectNameWithID($value->subject_id); ?>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca1; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca3; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca4; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->project; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->affective; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->psychomotor; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->ca1 + $value->ca3 + $value->ca4 + $value->project + $value->affective + $value->psychomotor; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo round($value->ca1 *40/60 + $value->ca3*40/60 + $value->ca4*40/60 + $value->project*40/60 + $value->affective*40/60 + $value->psychomotor*40/60, 1); ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo round($value->tot_score = $value->ca1 *40/60 + $value->ca3*40/60 + $value->ca4*40/60 + $value->project*40/60 + $value->affective*40/60 + $value->psychomotor*40/60 + $value->ca1 + $value->ca3 + $value->ca4 + $value->project + $value->affective + $value->psychomotor, 1); ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $grade; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $CI->GetHighestScore($value->subject_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id, $value->class_id); ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $CI->GetLowestScore($value->subject_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id); ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;white-space: nowrap;">
                                                <?php

$scores2 = $CI->GetSubjectScores($value->subject_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id); //echo $value->pos;

$scores = array_column($scores2, 'tot_score');

$pos = array_search($value->tot_score, $scores);
 //var_dump($pos);
 $number = $pos + 1;

echo $CI->ordinal($number);
?>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $remark; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have the database schema for the table `tot_score` of this model?

Comment: A quick (and dirty) option would be to create a function that calculates the exam scores and save them to the database and from there you can continue using what you've been using so far

Comment: @KoalaYeung I have modified the post. Is that what you mean by schema?

Comment: @user1165759 lol, I have no idea how to go about this. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, where you store exam no. you need to check a condition i.e. if the exam no. is empty then calculate the total ca(s) and then multiply and divide(apply your logic).

> **Remember this is only a temporary solution, once all the data is
>   saved, you should undo the changes or comment it out if you want to
>   use it later.**

**Controller -> function assigngradeSingleStudentAction() -> elseif condition** `//(I'm assuming this issue is only for elseif condition as your code suggests)`

```
else if($this->input->post('class') >= 4 && $this->input->post('class') <= 17)
{

    $data2['section_id']  = $this->input->post('section_id');
    $data2['subject_id']  = $this->input->post('subject_id');
    $data2['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
    $data2['student_id']  = $this->input->post('student_id');
    $data2['session_id']  = $this->input->post('session_id');
    $data2['ca1']         = $this->input->post('ca1');
    $data2['ca2']         = $this->input->post('ca2');
    $data2['ca3']         = $this->input->post('ca3');
    $data2['ca4']         = $this->input->post('ca4');
    $data2['project']     = $this->input->post('project');
    $data2['affective']   = $this->input->post('affective');
    $data2['psychomotor'] = $this->input->post('psychomotor');

    /* No change till here */
    if( !empty( $this->input->post('exam') )){

        $data2['exam']    = $this->input->post('exam');

    }else{

        $data2['exam']    = ( ( $data2['ca1'] + $data2['ca2'] + $data2['ca3'] + $data2['ca4']) * 40 )/ 60;
    }  // comment this else condition after your work is done.

    $data2['tot_score']   = $this->input->post('ca1') + $this->input->post('ca2') + $this->input->post('ca3') + $this->input->post('ca4') + $this->input->post('project') + $this->input->post('affective') + $this->input->post('psychomotor') + $data2['exam'];
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: I believe this should work for when scores are being added. What about scores that have already been added?

Comment: yes I do. Some scores have already been added. Will your solution help with it?

Comment: edit the form and then save it with the empty value in the exam number field, this should work.

Comment: I keep getting this error == Message: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'

Comment: Please could you check the controller again? I have modified it

Comment: thanks so much. Although I was met with errors, I was still able to use your code.

Comment: Hey @MamaJardel, sorry the internet was acting up, so I couldn't respond. I'm glad that you solved your problem and I could be of help. Also, it's a good practice to upvote the answer if you found it useful(in case you didn't know but if you did, forget what I just said). PS- Happy to help. :)

Comment: yes I tried to upvote but I don't think I have reach that level yet. However I marked your answer as the accepted one. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did using @sauhardnc solution

```
function assigngradeAction() 
{

            for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post('number')); $i++)
                {

                     $data[]=array(
                        'section_id' => $this->input->post('section_id'),
                        'subject_id' => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
                        'class_id' => $this->input->post('class_id')[$i],
                        'student_id' => $this->input->post('student_id')[$i],
                        'session_id' => $this->input->post('session_id'),
                        'ca1' => $this->input->post('ca1')[$i],
                        'ca2' => $this->input->post('ca2')[$i],
                        'ca3' => $this->input->post('ca3')[$i],
                        'ca4' => $this->input->post('ca4')[$i],
                        'project' => $this->input->post('project')[$i],
                        'affective' => $this->input->post('affective')[$i],
                        'psychomotor' => $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i],
                        'exam'=> !empty( $this->input->post('exam')[$i] ) ? $this->input->post('exam')[$i] : ($this->input->post('ca1')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca2')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca3')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca4')[$i] + $this->input->post('project')[$i] + $this->input->post('affective')[$i] + $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i]) * 40 / 60,
                        'tot_score'=> $this->input->post('ca1')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca2')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca3')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca4')[$i] + $this->input->post('project')[$i] + $this->input->post('affective')[$i] + $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i] + $this->input->post('exam')[$i] + ($this->input->post('ca1')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca2')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca3')[$i] + $this->input->post('ca4')[$i] + $this->input->post('project')[$i] + $this->input->post('affective')[$i] + $this->input->post('psychomotor')[$i]) * 40 / 60,
}   

                    );

                }




                 $inserted = $this->primary_model->add1($data);
                 if($inserted > 0)
                 {
                     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">Grade Added successfully</div>');
                     //Echo back success json
                     redirect('admin/primary/index');
                  }           

    }
```